# How can i search a pattern in a string and return an iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, pattern-matching

i want to find a pattern inside a string.using brute-force algorithm

```
int match(string p, string t) {
size_t n = t.size(), i = 0;
size_t m = p.size(), j = 0;
while (i < n && j < m) {
    if (p[j] == t[i]) {
        j++; i++;
    }
    else {
        i -= j - 1;
        j = 0;
    }
    }
return i - j;
}
```

but i am wondering how it worked in std::find_if.If there is a string "abab"and i will find "ab" Should i write my code like this`string::iterator it=find_if(s.begin(),s.end(),match)`? but it does not work,How should i write my code and tell me why?

Comment: `return p.find(t);` You are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem statement. Be more specific, such as is it a compiler error, wrong answer etc.

Comment: @FeiXiang ... which is what `string::find(const string&)` [does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I was dumb and I thought you were talking about `std::find()`.

Comment: @FeiXiang yes,my mistake,This is the compiler error,but as my capacity i can not tell you exactly where it happened.Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title says you want to return an iterator.  Iterators can be const or not. Declare two overloads and let the compiler sort it out.

```
std::string::iterator
match( std::string &p, const std::string& t) {
    return (p.begin() + p.find(t));
}

std::string::const_iterator
match( const std::string &p, const std::string& t) {
    return (p.begin() + p.find(t));
}
```

Comment: Sorry,i am still confused how can i call this function?`string::iterator it=match(s,"pattern")`?  That is wrong.Please tell me more details!

Comment: wait a moment.i will give it a try